# LSI 3042 supported with Oracle VM Server

Tags: virtual-machines, oracle, lsi

Trying to install an HP DL165 1U server with an LSI 3042 SAS card.

I get to the install, selected a language, select a keyboard screens then it asks me for a location for the driver (it doesn't tell me when one though but since it asks immediately after trying to load sas driver, I'm presuming it's this one).

Is the LSI 3042 (based on the same chipset as the LSI 3041) supported with Oracle VM Server?

Any idea where I can find the driver?

Edit: HP ProLiant G5

Comment: Which generation HP ProLiant DL165 server is this?

Comment: It's the G5 version.

Comment: Just in case someone else has this issue. The CD-Rom install of Oracle VM 3.2.2 (or any 3.x version for that matter) didn't work BUT the **FTP method DOES WORK**.

Answer (score 0):

The driver for the LSI cards is an MPT Fusion driver. Look for `mptsas`.

Comment: Hmm... It says it loads that when the server loads. Perhaps I'm confusing the issue & it's looking for a different driver? Is there any way to find out as it doesn't tell me on screen.